# How to refresh a gtk gui?

Tags: x11, firefox, gtk

After changing `Xft.dpi: 96` to `Xft.dpi: 192` in `~/.Xresources` I run `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` to enjoy a readable font size in Firefox on a 4K Monitor. However, I must kill and restart Firefox to do so. Is there another way to reload the Firefox GUI?

Edit: Might be a bug though https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1554850

Comment: There is none. The application reads on start and only itself. So Firefox would need to do so. What is the problem anyway, you only need to do so, once.

Comment: @WGRM some users as of the late 20th century often connect multiple monitors to their PC, or use laptops with docking stations. It is common for different models of monitor to have different DPIs. But also, what you said is totally not true, which you could have guessed by trying it from within gnome, or checked by reading the code of every GTK app ever written (after one or two you'd have seen there is a mechanism for this.)

Comment: @maaarghk We were talking about Xressources. I have read many times about it. The applications read it at start and there is no way to refresh the settings while running. So my answer was perfectly fine. See the only answer which states me correct. Im not into DBus yet, so i couldnt give this direction. So much about "totally not true". Totally unfounded.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to force a GTK app to reload the DPI built in to the framework itself. However, contrary to the comment you received, many GTK apps subscribe to the [`GSignal`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html) `notify::gtk-xft-dpi` on their [`GtkSettings`](https://gtk-d.dpldocs.info/gtk.Settings.Settings.html) instance.

If you use gnome, when you are in gnome-control-centre and you update the DPI, or you plug in a monitor, in the background gnome will send that signal to all GtkSettings instances and, if they implement it, they will update.

If you're not using a desktop environment, using `xrdb` will not send that signal. You should instead look to [`xsettingsd`](https://github.com/derat/xsettingsd). You should put your DPI settings in `~/.xsettingsd` as well as `~/.Xresources` and call `killall -HUP xsettingsd` when you change them. Careful, though, the `xsettingsd` DPI is `Xresources_DPI * 1024`.

I'm on i3 and to refresh/decrease the DPI of Chrome / terminal etc after I connect a monitor and disable my inbuilt high DPI screen, I have this configuration...

Added:

```
exec_always --no-startup-id xsettingsd
```

Updated:

```
bindsym $mod+Shift+c exec "i3 reload && killall -HUP xsettingsd"
```

I also added the following at the bottom of my screen layouts (with different numbers depending on which layout)...

```
echo "Xft.dpi: 135" | xrdb -merge
echo "Xft/DPI 138240" > ~/.xsettingsd
killall -HUP xsettingsd
i3 restart
sleep 3
nitrogen --restore
```